# Traceroute fails, ping fails, nslookup works

Tags: macos, network, big-sur

I am trying to debug a connectivity problem on macOS Big Sur.

**Symptoms**

After a few hours, the domain apple.com is unreachable from the device. All other domains are fine.

- `ping www.apple.com` fails to return anything (nothing printed on screen)
- `nslookup www.apple.com` returns an IP. When pinging this IP, it actually works

**What I tried**

- Given that pinging the IP but not the domain works, I tried resetting the DNS cache via : `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache ; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. This did not help.
- I ran `tcpdump` on both the device and the router. Nothing showed up.
- I ran `traceroute` on the device, it does not even show the first hop to the router.

Any pointer to solve this?

EDIT:

I've spent a lot of time on this, still without success. Rebooting the router does not sort out the issue. `dig` works fine, `nslookup` works fine. `dscacheutil` fails. For some reason, it does not show the IPv4 address :

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name www.apple.com
name: e6858.dscx.akamaiedge.net
alias: www.apple.com www.apple.com.edgekey.net www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net 
ipv6_address: 2a02:26f0:7400:1ac::1aca
ipv6_address: 2a02:26f0:7400:1ad::1aca
```

When I add the line `127.0.0.1 apple.com` to `/etc/hosts`, then it works and I see this :

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name www.apple.com
name: e6858.dscx.akamaiedge.net
alias: www.apple.com www.apple.com.edgekey.net www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net 
ipv6_address: 2a02:26f0:7400:1ad::1aca
ipv6_address: 2a02:26f0:7400:1ac::1aca

name: e6858.dscx.akamaiedge.net
alias: www.apple.com www.apple.com.edgekey.net www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net 
ip_address: 2.21.169.157
```

I have no idea why pointing to the loopback address suddenly solves the problem.

EDIT2 :

While `dscacheutil` contains only the IPv6 addresses for `www.apple.com`, it contains ipv4 addresses for `apple.com` :

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name apple.com
name: apple.com
ip_address: 17.253.144.10
```

So I can indeed access `apple.com` but not `www.apple.com`. Does that make sense to anyone?

Comment: When you say that "ping www.apple.com" fails to return anything - do you mean that literally nothing is printed on screen or? - Please include exactly what is shown on screen when running the command - either small screenshot or by copy-pasting the text.

Comment: correct. Nothing at all gets printed on screen. I will make it clearer.

Comment: So to clarify - nothing is printed on screen, but the program hang or do you get the command prompt again? If it hangs, how long time have you left it running?

Comment: It hangs, for several minutes. Any other website will answer the ping, within about 10 ms max.

Comment: When it hangs for several minutes that has nothing to do with the web site answering the ping, that means that it is waiting for DNS resolution - so you have a local DNS configuration issue

Comment: Ah interesting. Ok, thanks. That's also what I thought, but when flushing the cache, it didn't solve the problem. I feel it should have, so I am not sure what else to try?

Comment: There’s no logical reason why flushing the cache would solve the problem. It doesn’t make sense, so I don’t know why you feel that. You need to fix your configuration instead. I.e. check in Network in System Preferences which IP addresses you have listed as your DNS servers - and either make sure they respond, or change them to some that do.

Comment: Hmm, because the problem appears only after a while (several hours) and is fixed by restarting the computer, I felt that flushing the cache would work simlarly to restarting.

Comment: It doesn’t…………..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nslookup` bypasses the "normal" DNS resolution done by macOS and instead seems to implement its own lookup (`dig` does as well, as I painfully learned during some debugging). Both `nslookup` and `dig` are actually [third-party tools by ISC](https://bind.isc.org/doc/arm/9.11/man.nslookup.html) (which also make BIND).

To use an "Apple-native" command for DNS lookups, try `dscacheutil`:

```
dscacheutil -q host -a name www.apple.com
```

You can see the DNS settings macOS is using with:

```
scutil --dns
```

The problem you describe sounds like the DNS config is either incorrect and/or the configured DNS server are not responding (or responding with "not found" answers). The ISC tools might still work in this case as they rely on `/etc/resolv.conf` instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that @DarkDust. I will run the commands you suggest as soon as the problem manifests again (I have restarted the device, so need to wait some time before it manifests again). When the problem was there this morning, I did flush the cache, but it didn't solve the problem. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: It makes sense if, as I wrote, the DNS config is incorrect at that time. For example, DNS server not responding or responding with "not found".

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I will explore that.

Comment: Ok, the problem reappeared. When I run `dscacheutil -q host -a name www.apple.com`, nothing appears. It just hangs. When I tried to run this command when the problem was not present, it returned proper values.  Regarding `scutil --dns` it works properly and returns the same values whether the problem manifests or not.

Comment: This sounds like some service is hanging or is down, but I'm afraid I have no idea where to search. `Console.app` might give hints.

Comment: I have added `0.0.0.0 apple.com` to the `/etc/hosts` file. This fixed the problem. I then removed this line, and it continued to work fine. I have no idea why though... Next time the problem manifests I'll look at the console as you suggest. Thanks for your help